# How to label specific words as in a diagram

Tags: text-decorations

I would like to add descriptions to specific words as in `ls` and `foo.bar` in the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

An easy but less flexible solution uses the [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) package and its `\underbracket` macro.

You can change the outcome of the bracket with the two optional arguments of `\underbracket`:

```
\underbracket[<rule thickness>][<bracket height>]{<arg>}
```

The other solution uses TikZ (if you want less flexibility in the drawing it might be better to use PGF for performance reasons).

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,tikz}
\newcommand*{\underDesc}[2]{%
  $\underbracket{\smash[b]{\text{\,#1\,}}}_{\text{#2}}$}

\tikzset{
  underDesc line/.style={draw,rounded corners=\pgflinewidth, line cap=round},
  underDesc node/.style={
    anchor=base, text depth=+0pt, inner ysep=+0pt, inner xsep=.1667em, outer sep=+0pt},
  underDesc node*/.style={
    inner xsep=+0pt, inner ysep=+1pt, font=\scriptsize},
  underDesc path/.style={
    underDesc line, to path={-- ++(down:.7ex) -|
      node[below, near start, underDesc node*] {#1} (\tikztotarget)}}}
\newcommand*{\underDescTikZ}[3][]{%
  \tikz[baseline, #1]
    \node[underDesc node, append after command={
        (\tikzlastnode.south west) edge[underDesc path={#3}] (\tikzlastnode.south east)}
      ] {#2};}
\begin{document}
\underDesc{Is}{word}
\underDesc{foo.bar}{word}
\bigskip

\underDescTikZ{Is}{word}
\underDescTikZ[underDesc line/.append style={draw=red}]{foo.bar}{word}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This solution uses the `stackengine` package.  Here, I use two nested `\stackunder` macros to place the brace and the underword below the primary argument.  The rule thickness of the brace, its color, and its vertical separation below the primary argument are all resettable with the `\def`s given in this MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\thk{.4ex}%       RULE THICKNESS
\def\vsep{1pt}%       SEPARATION BETEEN PRIMARY WORD AND UNDERBRACE
\def\bracecolor{red}% BRACE COLOR
\def\bracestrut{\hsmash{\rule{\thk}{1ex}}}
\newcommand\ubrace[2]{%
  \stackunder[-2pt]{%
    \stackunder[\vsep]{#1}{%
      \color{\bracecolor}\bracestrut\rule{\widthof{#1}}{\thk}\bracestrut%
    }%
  }{\strut\scriptsize#2}
}
\begin{document}
\ubrace{foo}{word} ~ \ubrace{foo.bar}{macro}
\end{document}
```

[image]